# Connect to firestore from python app running on app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, fastapi

I am running a fastapi app on app engine and trying to connect to firestore from it. When I am running it locally, I use the credentials file to connect to the db like this and it works fine :

```
cred = credentials.ApplicationDefault()
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
```

Now when I deploy the app on app engine, I tried establishing the connection like

```
firebase_admin.initialize_app()
db = firestore.client()
itemsList = []
if (items := db.collection("items").stream()) is not None:
    for item in items:
        itemsList.append(item.to_dict())
    return itemsList
```

Though this do not throw an error on connecting,while trying to read or write from the DB I am getting the following error :

> google.api_core.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 503 Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: ("Failed to retrieve http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/service-account-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com/token?scopes=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform%2Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdatastore%2Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdevstorage.read_write%2Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Ffirebase%2Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fidentitytoolkit%2Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email from the Google Compute Engine metadata service. Status: 500 Response:\nb'Could not fetch URI /computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/service-account-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com/token?scopes=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform%2Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdatastore%2Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdevstorage.read_write%2Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Ffirebase%2Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fidentitytoolkit%2Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email\n'", <google.auth.transport.requests._Response object at 0x3e0388845610>)

Both the app and firestore are located in the same app engine project. I figure I am missing some kind of permissions but I am not sure what exactly am I doing wrong. All tutorials I came across suggested to use the default authentication for authenticating from google cloud environments to firestore and that is what I have been doing.

Comment: What I see looks ok. Show your code for `trying to read or write from the DB`.

Comment: If possible can you share reproducible steps so It can be solved by that way ?

Comment: @newname Updated the question with the code I am using for trying to read from firestore.